# I cannot use Devart with Entity Framework Core on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, devart

I found that most of the dotConnect versions (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL) are compatible with EFCore. However, seems that it does not work with SQL Server. Is there something I missed? I have been using Devart with EF Core on other project for a while and it's super fancy. May I know if there a way to use dotConnect with EF Core? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Devart Entity Developer for Entity Framework](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/editions.html) to generate EF Core Model for SQL Server via standard System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Thank you @Devart . btw, may I know if dotConnect support in-memory efcore as well?

Comment: The EF Core template includes the !optionsBuilder.IsConfigured check for setting optionsBuilder.Use... in the generated OnConfiguring method. So, if you pass optionsBuilder.Options configured for using in-memory to your context constructor, you can work with in-memory.